# Python3 pip module, check if packages exist on PyPi

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I use the pip module in a python script to automate the installation of software / modules . How can I do to check if the (remote) software / module exists? I have found nothing in the pip module that allows to do that.

My code :

```
class install_pip:
    def __init__(self):
        self._liste=['install']
    def install(self):
        pip.main(self._liste)
    def addsoftware(self, software):
        if type(software) is str:
            self._liste.append(software)
        if type(software) is list:
            for i in software:
                self._liste.append(i)
    def delsoftware(self, software):
        if type(software) is str:
            self._liste.remove(software)
        if type(software) is list:
            for i in software:
                self._liste.remove(i)
    def _return(self):
        return self._liste[1:len(self._liste)]
    list = property(_return)
```

I want check if 'software' exist.
Thanks.

Edit: I tried this code:

```
try:
    pip.main(['install', 'nonexistentpackage'])
except pip.InstallationError as err:
    print(echec)
```

But I dont get any error...

Answer (score 3):

I would do this:

```
import requests
response = requests.get("http://pypi.python.org/pypi/{}/json"
                        .format(module_name))
if response.status_code == 200:
    # OK, the json document exists so you can
    # parse the module details if you want
    # by using data = response.json()
    #
    # anyway, here you know that the module exists!
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question, but this works for me.

```
from importlib import util

found = True if util.find_spec('packagename') is not None else False
if found:
    import packagename
else:
    pip.main(['install', packagename])
    import packagename
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
async function check() {
  const packages = document.querySelector('textarea').value.split('\n')
  const settled = await Promise.allSettled(packages.map(n=>fetch(`https://pypi.org/pypi/${n}/json`, {method: 'HEAD'})))
  document.all.output.innerHTML = settled.map((s, i) => s.status === 'fulfilled' ? `<font color="green"><b>${packages[i]}</b></font>` : packages[i]).join('\n')
}
check()
```

```html
<textarea oninput="check()" rows="5">requests&#10;nonexistentpackage</textarea>
<pre id=output></pre>
```

Answer (score -2):

The following code will attempt to import a package (package is of type 'str'). If it is unable to import the package (i.e. it isn't installed) it will call Pip and attempt to install the package.

```
import pip

def import_or_install(package):
    try:
        __import__(package)
        print (package, "exists, and was successfully imported.")
    except ImportError:
        pip.main(['install', package])

import_or_install("name of package")
```

Comment: Thank but that does not test if the remote package exists, is there a Pythonic way to access the cache of installable software ?